# How to instrument Dagger 2 to measure/trace creation time of different parts of the dependency graph?

Tags: dagger-2

Does anyone know anyway or library to instrument Dagger 2 and set traces to see how long each module takes to create on startup?

We are trying to reduce cold startup time of an Android time and we would like to be able to measure how much time is spent on creating each module that is built on startup so that we can track over time which modules are taking up more time, and find out where is it worth to spend time trying to defer some initializations.

I have found this online: http://frogermcs.github.io/dagger2metrics-measure-performance-of-graph-initialization/ but couldn’t really make it work

I skimmed through Dagger2 code, considering to try to add traces to the code generated tasks, but it seemed like a daunting task and we don't want to maintain a fork.